# The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"CoursesPlaylistScreen"} was not handled by any navigator in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I have tried nesting the naviagtors so I don't have to face this issue but still I am getting this error as I have main navigator which is contains the first screen `BootcampWeeksScreen.js` then I can easily navigating through it new screen which contains `const tab= createMaterialTopTabNavigator()`.

BootcampWeeksScreen.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";
import Courses from "./BootcampAdditionalScreens/Courses";
import Tests from "./BootcampAdditionalScreens/Test";
import Roadmap from "./BootcampAdditionalScreens/Roadmap";
import CoursesPlaylistScreen from "../screens/BootcampAdditionalScreens/CoursesPlaylistScreen.js";
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const BootcampWeeksScreen=()=>{
  return (

    <NavigationContainer>

      <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{ scrollEnabled: true }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Course" component={Courses} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Tests" component={Tests} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Roadmap" component={Roadmap} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
 function App() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
          <Stack.Screen name="BootcampWeeksScreen" component={BootcampWeeksScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="CoursesPlaylistScreen" component={CoursesPlaylistScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }

  export default BootcampWeeksScreen;
```

Now I want to navigate through the screen `CoursesPlaylistScreen` from the `Course` screen but I am getting this error and also I have tried nesting the navigators.

I have tried this also to navigate though the screen: ```onPress={() =>navigation.navigate("BootcampStack",{screen:"CoursesPlaylistScreen"})}  ````

Still, I am getting this error.

```
 ERROR  The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"CoursesPlaylistScreen"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'CoursesPlaylistScreen'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.
```

I don't know How can I do this?

Comment: I think you should not use TWO NavigationContainer.const BootcampWeeksScreen=()=>{
  return (
      <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{ scrollEnabled: true }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Course" component={Courses} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Tests" component={Tests} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Roadmap" component={Roadmap} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

Comment: @SlavaVasilenko I tried this but I got an error `Error: Couldn't register the navigator. Have you wrapped your app with 'NavigationContainer'?`

Comment: I created working example for you. I hope this help https://snack.expo.dev/JIbD5QU_Y

Comment: @SlavaVasilenko I tried what you have suggested but I got an error `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `StackNavigator`.`

Comment: @SlavaVasilenko I have already `exported default` my component.

Comment: I created snack for you in one file. Just check all imports

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238519/discussion-between-slava-vasilenko-and-harsh-mishra).

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one NavigationContainer. Try removing NavigationContainer from BootcampWeeksScreen.

Comment: Still getting same error `The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"CoursesPlaylistScreen"} was not handled by any navigator.`

Answer (score 1):

The NavigationContainer is responsible for managing your app state and linking your top-level navigator to the app environment. By giving two navigators, you're resetting the whole navigator and hence unable to find the other stack.

You should only wrap your stacks in NavigationContainer on the root/top level of your navigation, i.e. function App in your situation.

Comment: I tried this but I got an error `Error: Couldn't register the navigator. Have you wrapped your app with 'NavigationContainer'?`

Comment: Can you show me what is wrapped inside NavigationContainer?

Comment: I have added it in my post. Please see